# Random sample according to distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I return multiple unique items from a list, according to a probability distribution?

`random.sample(population, k)` is exactly what I want, but sadly it doesn't take a probability distribution.

`random.choices(population, weights, k)` is also almost what I want, except its output can contain the same member of the population more than once

```py
>>> random.choices([1, 2], [0.5, 0.5], k=2)
[1, 1]
```

For those arguments, I would like the output to always be `[1, 2]` or `[2, 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) is probably what you want. You can:

- call it with `replace=False` to sample without replacement
- specify probability weights through parameter `p`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @alexis_thual, use [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). Here is an example of how it would work for what you want:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.choice([1, 2], size=2, replace=False, p=[0.5, 0.5])
```

Answer (score -4):

The random.choices() function in Python's random module allows you to generate a random sample from a population while specifying weights for each item. However, as you mentioned, it can produce duplicate items in the output.

To generate a random sample according to a probability distribution without duplicates, you can combine `random.choices()` with `set()` to remove duplicate items from the result.
**Here is an example:**

```py
import random

population = [1, 2]
weights = [0.5, 0.5]
k = 2

sample = set(random.choices(population, weights, k))
result = list(sample)

# If the number of unique items in the sample is less than k, repeat the process until it matches
while len(result) < k:
    sample = set(random.choices(population, weights, k - len(result)))
    result.extend(list(sample))

print(result)
```

This code will generate a random sample of `k` items from the `population` list, based on the given `weights`. The `set()` function is used to remove any duplicate items from the sample. If the number of unique items in the sample is less than `k`, the code repeats the sampling process until it has enough unique items.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't work with e.g. `[1, 1, 2]` as the population list

Comment: Apart from AI-generated answers being prohibited here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy), `result.extend(list(sample))` doesn't account for the possiblity that the new `sample` may contain items that also appear in the existing `result`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, David Suzuki!

Several of your answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.